# Generating unique position key for every chess position

Tags: c, random, hash, chess

I am trying to create a chess engine. I was told that we can generate unique key for any chess position by hashing individual piece keys. Its like a particular piece on a particular square has an unique 64 bit key. Then we are supposed to XOR the piece keys for every piece present in the position.

Ignoring the castling and the en Passant square information about a chess position, here is how I was told to generate a position key(in C language)

```
typedef unsigned long long U64;
#define RAND_64 (   (U64) rand() + \
                    (U64) rand() << 15 + \
                    (U64) rand() << 31 + \
                    (U64) rand() << 45 \
                )
```

Here is how the piece keys are generated from RAND 64 declared above...

```
int index, index2;
U64 pieceKeys[12][64]; // For 12 pieces on every possible square.

for(index = 0; index<12; index++) {
    for(index2 = 0; index2<64; index2++) { 
        pieceKeys[index][index2] = RAND_64;
    }
}
```

My question is that here isn't there a possibility of generating the same piece key for 2 pieces on 2 squares. If that happens then there will be ambiguity when we create the position key by XOR ing the piece keys.

Am I right? If so then how can I solve this potential problem?

Comment: There's no actual executing code here, save for the declaration of an array of arrays. Perhaps you can show how that RAND_64 is used in the code you're writing as part of your question.

Comment: ok I will add that part as well

Comment: Here is a question related to this on [chess.se] (which might be a better place to ask than here): [engines - How to generate hash keys for chess positions](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/18670/15148).

Comment: I was about to ask in that forum only. But I found that there were no tags for things like C Language. Hashing etc. So I thought this might be better place.

Comment: Since you ar filling your Zobrist table with (three) rand()s, it is not impossible (but highly unlikely) that two entries will get the same value. But, you could test for these duplicates and pull a new set of values from rand() for every cell that happens to have a duplicated value.

Comment: @joop isn't it waste of time checking for duplicates everytime for something that has such a low chance of happening?

Comment: The Zobrist table is only 12 *64 in size, and basically constant (maybe initialized at program start)

Comment: Since there are (considerably) more than 2^64 possible chessboards, it's impossible to create a 64-bit hashcode which uniquely identifies a position. So you need to deal with hash collisions, regardless of hashing algorithm.

Comment: Your nested loop doesn't account for blank squares. Unless you want to represent all blank squares with the same XOR term, which is less random, you should increase the "piece" dimension from 12 to 13.

Comment: Your `RAND_64` is probably producing a 60 bit value (4 * 15 bits), so you may want to add `(u64) rand() << 60` to get the full 64 bits. Also `<<` has lower operator precedence than `+`, so you need parentheses around all the `<<` subexpressions.

Comment: @rici Indeed, the 64-bit value for the overall board position won't be unique even though the piece-key terms being XOR'd together are unique, because the operation is lossy. I think the idea is that collisions should be unlikely for positions considered during a game. Since the main purpose is to note which positions have been already "seen", ignoring collisions just means that some positions may be examined more than once. The position code should also vary depending on whether it is black's or white's turn to move.

Comment: @IanAbbott: Yes, as well as aspects of state mentioned in the second para of the OP. But that doesn't need to be hashed, because its unlikely that you will hit the same position with two different states *in the same game*. Similarly, the unlikely event of a duplicate entry in the Zobrist table probably doesn't lead to hash collisions, since it's unlikely that you'd encounter two positions in the same game which differed only by the substitution of one piece/location for another one. (Slightly less unlikely if it's the same piece in both cases, I suppose.)

Comment: @joop You could use a known PRNG with a known initial seed (determined empirically) to avoid duplicates during initialization of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only 6 different types of chess pieces and then there is black and white. Use 1 bit for black or white and 3 bits for the piece type and 7 bits for the square number, e.g.:

```
// square numbes are 0x0000 thru 0x007F
#define BLACK 0x0080
#define WHITE 0x0000

#define KING   0x0100
#define QUEEN  0x0200
#define ROOK   0x0400
#define BISHOP 0x0800
#define KNIGHT 0x1000
#define PAWN   0x2000

#define PIECE_MASK    0x3F00
#define SQUARE_MASK   0x007F
```

and use bit masking to determine them:

```
int color= board[x][y] & BLACK; // non zero if black; zero if white
int is_king= board[x][y] & KING;
int squarenum= board[x][y] & SQUARE_MASK;

int piece= board[x][y] & PIECE_MASK;
switch (piece>>8) {
    case 1: //King
    case 2: //Queen
    case 4: //Rook
    case 8: //Bishop
    case 16://Knight
    case 32://Pawn
}
```

Comment: what is the variable square supposed to represent in "int color = square & BLACK;"?

Comment: That would of course be a square of the board. Replaced it with board[x][y].

Comment: Surely you only need 6 bits for the position of each piece? And you used 6 bits for the piece type instead of 3. So each piece only needs 10 bits in total. Multiply by 32 pieces and you get 320 bits for the board position, plus 1 bit to encode whether it black or whites turn at that position. This has no collisions.